# Multiple node cassandra cluster is really slow

Tags: performance, amazon-ec2, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I had a single node cassandra cluster on EC2. I was running my tests on it and it worked great.

But then, I had to move this cluster to a VPC, so rather than moving the data, I created a new cluster with two nodes (both seeds), and imported the data from the former cluster using `sstableloader`.

I thought it was really slow, so decided to add two more instances (not seeds). It's even slower.

I use a ONE consistency, and my replication factor is 1, so I don't quite see why it is so slow.

To give you an idea, **I can only do 3 read per second**.
We use the EC2Snitch but not the AMI recommended by Cassandra though (we didn't see that part in the documentation when we installed it).

I didn't run a cleanup yet on the two first nodes after adding the two new nodes.

When I request all elements of a column family which contains only a dozen of rows, it times out. If I request **one** element, I get the result after a long time, and with a **huge tracing session** (~30000 lines...)!

Does anyone know what I can do to make it faster? I don't quite know where to look at right now.

My Cassandra version is Cassandra 2.1.3.
Here is my keyspace schema:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE keyspace_name WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'us-west-2': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

And the options for our column family

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace_name."CFName" (
    // ...
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'min_threshold': '4', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

Comment: Including the version you are using, your keyspace/table schema, and the query trace would all be helpful information. Edit: pastie the trace and link to it :)

Comment: @mshuler: Done, I can't reproduce the error I had unfortunately (I get my results) but it is still extremely slow!

Comment: @JulienFouilhé Can you provide the output of nodetool status, tpstats and netstats ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to run a compaction on my nodes because I had [too many tombstones](https://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_about_deletes_c.html).

Many thanks to the amazing IRC channel on freenode #cassandra.